# SPARQL Query Execution time using Jena on a Virtuoso service

Tags: java, sparql, jena, execution-time, virtuoso

So I am using a Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint and I am using Jena to query it. I use `QueryFactory` and `QueryExecution` to create a SPARQL query :

```
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQueryString1);
    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://localhost:8890/sparql", query);
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
```

Now I want to calculate the time taken to run this query. How does one find such a time using Jena on Virtuoso? Is that possible? Obviously I did look at functions like `getTimeOut1()` and `getTimeOut2()`. They don't seem to be giving me any good direction. As a hack I tried using Java's inbuilt `System.currentTimeMillis()`, However I am not sure if that is the right way. Any pointers as to how I can find execution time would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Results come back as a stream so the timing needs to span from just before `qexec.execSelect()` to just after the app finished handling the results, not just call `execSelect`.

```
Timer timer = new Timer() ;
timer.startTimer() ;
ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.consume(results) ;
long x = timer.finishTimer() ;   // Time in milliseconds.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @AndyS. For now I am using this, but however, is there any other way to figure out how long it takes to run queries on Virtuoso? i.e. how long Virtuoso takes? In any case this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you want to time the full round-trip, or just the time Virtuoso spends on things...

Virtuoso 7 lets you get the compilation (query plan) and execution time of a query using [the `profile` function](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/databaseadmsrv.html#readingqueryprofile).

You can also enable general query logging and profiling using [the `prof_enable` function](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/databaseadmsrv.html#querylogging).

Comment: Thanks a lot @TallTed. Obviously I just wanted to figure out how long Virtuoso takes. What I need is a simple and easy API call to the system to find a Query Execution time. The need stems from running more than one similar query to find changes in execution time. I guess there is no way to do it using JENA or rdflib. I only know of the profile function that would let me do it using Virtuoso. Thanks for the tip!